# How to pre-pull docker images in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to dockerize an existing script which runs docker containers himself: this results in a docker in docker schema.

Currently, I am able to build a basic docker image with docker installed in it along with my scripts' code dependencies. Unfortunately, each time I run this image, a new container is created based on this image and needs to pull all the docker images needed to run my script (with an `ENTRYPOINT` script). This takes a lot of time and feels wrong.

I would like to be able to pre-pull the docker images required by my script inside the  Dockerfile so that all child containers do not need to do so.

The thing is, I cannot manage to launch the docker service in the Dockerfile and it is needed to pull those images.

Am I doing things correctly? Should i completely revisit my approach? Or what should i adapt?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:buster

# Install docker
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl 
RUN curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
RUN sh ./get-docker.sh

# I tried:
# RUN docker pull hello-world
# RUN dockerd && docker pull hello-world
# RUN service docker start && docker pull hello-world
```

Comment: mount /var/lib/docker on a volume or bind it to a local directory. Caution: if you do this, make sure you only launch 1 instance at a time. Accessing that dir concurrently from several docker instances will end in unexpected results.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to run the orchestrator inside a container; can you run it directly on the host system (the same way you do other container orchestrators like Docker Compose)?  Docker-in-Docker is a complex and confusing setup and I'd try very hard to avoid it.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to run this docker image in Kubernetes. `docker-compose` or accessing the host is out of the question in this scenario. Is there a preferred way of doing this?

Comment: @DavidMaze I need to run the orchestrator in the container because the main script does a `docker run ...` at some point and waits for the results of this command.

Comment: ...but why do you need to specifically run it inside a container?  Also note, if eventually you're planning to run this in Kubernetes, `docker run` won't work there and you'll need the Kubernetes APIs instead.

Comment: Well currently I am installing docker inside the Kubernetes pod, so `docker run` should work. I don't _need_ to run it inside a container, i might just be lacking some knowledge on how I am supposed to do this. Now, the `docker run` launches a container which requires access to the scripts' filesystem. I was planning on installing docker inside my container and sharing a volume for this to work. Should i do the same but with the Kubernetes API ?